# How to add http:// if it doesn't exist in a string containing multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

**String which I am checking:**

```
   Unroll the pastry on to a lightly floured work surface. Cut is [Google](www.google.com/) 
    into 2 long rectangles. Cut the large rectangle in half lengthways, then cut both smaller reckk
    Bake in the oven for 25–30 minutes, or until the pastry has turned golden-brown and looks crisp. 
    Remove from the oven and leave to cool slightly before serving. Unroll the pastry on to a lightly floured work surface. 
    this is my [web](www.stackoverflow.com), this is [Google](https://www.google.com/) 
    Cut into 2 long rectangles. Cut the large rectangle in half lengthways, then cut both smaller rectangles into eight equal sections. You now have 16 rectangles in total.
    Brush one end of each rectangle with a little of the beaten egg
```

Above is the string from which I am checking the URL if the URL's doesn't have http or https I am adding it using below logic but problem here is it just check the first URL and replace it if http or https doesn't exist no other URL's are changed which don't have http or https

Below is the logic which I had applied:

```
  async urlify(text) {
   var urlRegex = new RegExp(
  '([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?'
   );
  return await text.replace(urlRegex, (url) => {
   if (url.search(/^http[s]?\:\/\//) === -1) {
    return 'http://' + url;
   } else {
     return url;
   }
  });
  }
```

Can anyone please let me know what's wrong here?

Comment: Why is the function async? It doesn't need to be

Comment: This is some pretty flawed logic as well, considering TLDs can be longer than 4 characters, and hostnames don't need any dot separators at all to work.  So naturally some tradeoffs will need to be made, but yeah.  Something to keep in mind.

Comment: Look like MarkDown links, why don't you just use a MarkDown parser to convert ithe text to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`g`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) modifier. Without it, your regexp will only find the first match.
Also, `String.replace()` doesn't return a Promise. You don't need `await`.

```js
const str = ` Unroll the pastry on to a lightly floured work surface. Cut is [Google](www.google.com/) 
    into 2 long rectangles. Cut the large rectangle in half lengthways, then cut both smaller reckk
    Bake in the oven for 25–30 minutes, or until the pastry has turned golden-brown and looks crisp. 
    Remove from the oven and leave to cool slightly before serving. Unroll the pastry on to a lightly floured work surface. 
    this is my [web](www.stackoverflow.com), this is [Google](https://www.google.com/) 
    Cut into 2 long rectangles. Cut the large rectangle in half lengthways, then cut both smaller rectangles into eight equal sections. You now have 16 rectangles in total.
    Brush one end of each rectangle with a little of the beaten egg`;
    
function urlify(text) {
   var urlRegex = new RegExp(
    '([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?', 
    'g'
   );
  return text.replace(urlRegex, (url) => {
   if (url.search(/^http[s]?\:\/\//) === -1) {
    return 'http://' + url;
   } else {
     return url;
   }
  });
}
  
console.log(urlify(str));
```